# node.id vs broker.id in KRaft mode

Tags: apache-kafka, kraft

The default config for running Kafka in KRaft mode (in `config/kraft/server.properties`) does not have `broker.id`. Instead it has `node.id`. What is the difference between these fields? Confluent says to set `broker.id.generation.enable=true` when not running in KRaft mode. Is there an equivalent value when running KRaft mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that `broker.id` is for installs that use Zookeeper and `node.id` is for installs that use KRaft. There is no equivalent `broker.id.generation.enable` when using KRaft.

Answer (score 0):

> broker.id *OR* broker.id.generation.enable

To add a Kafka broker to our cluster, we just start a new Kafka broker with a unique ID. This ID can either be created with the configuration broker.id or with `broker.id.generation.enable` set to `true`. And go with Zookeeper

> node.id

The unique identifier for this server And go with [KRaft](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/7.6/installation/configuration/broker-configs.html#node-id)